# Summation of Recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, recurrence-relations

We have a function defined as :

$h(x+2)$= $ 2h(x+1)$ + $2-h(x)$ when x is even ,

$h(x+2)$=$ 3h(x)$ when x is odd.

Given two numbers $a,b$ where $a\le b$

We need to find $$\sum_{n=a}^{b} h(n)$$

$h(2)= 1 $ & $h(1)= 1$

From the second relation , i got the values of 
$h(2k+1)$= $3^{k}$ for $k \ge 1$.

I also figured out that the summation of even terms will be a GP , but cant seem to generalize the values of even function.
So how do we get the summation value ?

Comment: Perhaps the summand $h(y)$ is wrong. Otherwise, that sum is just $h(y)\sum_{n=a}^b=(b-a) h(y)$, since the input of the function h is independent of the summation index $n.$

Comment: Noted and edited.

Comment: @Avisolanki Answer to your query:- sum/2 will always minimize the difference as if one part is sum/2 other will be sum/2 as well(common sense) and difference always comes very close to zero :-)

Comment: lets continue the discussion in personal chat.

Comment: @Guhfg gehlthon how do we use personal chat ? i dont know how to do that are you on slack ? we can continue the discussion there .

Comment: @Avisolanki As you say..

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon The workspace is live. Please join ASAP, thanks

Comment: Please join [Slack](https://join.slack.com/t/algorithms-bal5117/shared_invite/enQtNjY4MDAxMzgyNTk0LWI5ZGUzZDhjNDIzNTg5ZDQyNmNkODc1ZjQ2ZTZmNGNjZjkyYzJkNDNmNDYwY2ZkMGJiMWI0NjIzYTM4NjY2YmE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x = 2k$ is even,

$$\begin{align*}
h(2k+2) &= 2h(2k+1) + 2 - h(2k)\\
&= 2\cdot 3^k + 2 - h(2k)\\
&= 2\cdot 3^k + 2 - \left[2\cdot 3^{k-1} + 2 - h(2k-2)\right]\\
&= 2\cdot 3^k\left(1 - 3^{-1}\right) + 2\left(1 - 1\right) + h(2k-2)\\
&= 2\cdot 3^k\left(1 - 3^{-1}\right) + 2\left(1 - 1\right) + \left[2\cdot 3^{k-2} + 2 - h(2k-4)\right]\\
&= 2\cdot 3^k\left(1 - 3^{-1} + 3^{-2}\right) + 2\left(1 - 1+1\right) + h(2k-4)\\
&= \vdots\\
&= 2\cdot 3^k\sum_{i=0}^n(-3^{-1})^{i} + 2\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i -(-1)^n h(2k-2n)\\
&= 2\cdot3^k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(-3^{-1})^{i} + 2\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(-1)^i -(-1)^{k-1} h(2)&(n=k-1)\\
&= 2\cdot 3^k \frac{1-(-3^{-1})^k}{1-(-3^{-1})} + 2\frac{1-(-1)^k}{1-(-1)} + (-1)^k\\
&= 2\cdot 3^k \cdot \frac34\left[1-(-3^{-1})^k\right] + [1-(-1)^{k}] + (-1)^k\\
&= \frac{3^{k+1}}{2} - \frac32(-1)^k - (-1)^k + (-1)^k + 1\\
&= \frac{3^{k+1}}{2} + \frac{3(-1)^{k+1}}{2} + 1
\end{align*}$$

Then if you sum even and odd $n$ separately in $\sum_{n=a}^b h(n)$, the sum would contain more Geometric series additions.

Comment: If (2k+1)==> odd, h(2k+1)=3^k, am I right??

Comment: For h(x) , where 'x' is even, you've calculated the sum above..I mean the answer of h(x)....now, while summing it up, I know that I have to apply gp formulas...but I've a small doubt...how to prove that the value of function h(x) will always be an integer ??

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon The OP figured out $h(2k+1)=3^k$, so I did not prove it.

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon The last line of $h(2k+2)$ is

$$\frac{3^{k+1}}2 + \frac{3(-1)^{k+1}}2 + 1 = \frac32\left[3^k - (-1)^k\right] +1$$

Either consider that both $3^k$ and $(-1)^k$ are odd and so their difference is even, or factorise it using $$a^k-b^k = (a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^{k-1-i}b^i$$

for $k\ge 1$ (which is just another restatement of GP sum).